# move box from right to left continously using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to move box right then left and again right left continously but it make only one cycle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function a() {
    $('#foo').css({
      'right': window.innerWidth - $('#foo').width(),
      'left': 'auto'
    }).animate({
      'right': '0px'
    }, 9000, function() {
      $('#foo').animate({
        'left': '0px'
      }, 9000, a);
    });
  }
  a();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" style="background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute" ></div>
```

any help ??

Comment: for me your example works as you need without problems

Comment: I am voting to close this question as the code is working as desired already and the problem can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works without any problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function a() {
    $('#foo').css({
      'right': window.innerWidth - $('#foo').width(),
      'left': 'auto'
    }).animate({
      'right': '0px'
    }, 9000, function() {
      $('#foo').animate({
        'left': '0px'
      }, 9000, a);
    });
  }
  a();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" style="background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute" ></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n7u7q42d/

Probably you have loaded multiple libraries. Could you post errors please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code already does what you are asking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function a() {
    $('#foo').css({
      'right': window.innerWidth - $('#foo').width(),
      'left': 'auto'
    }).animate({
      'right': '0px'
    }, 9000, function() {
      $('#foo').animate({
        'left': '0px'
      }, 9000, a);
    });
  }
  a();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" style="background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute" ></div>
```

But, you can also accomplish the same thing with much better performance if you use use **[CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)**:

```css
#foo { 
  background: red; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  position: absolute; 
  left:0px;  /* This is the property that will be animated */
  animation:9s leftRight infinite;  /* configure the animation */
}

@keyframes leftRight {

  0% {
    left:0;
  }
  
  50% {
    left:calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  
  100% {
    left:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```